# Symfony service as global twig variable

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a service called `General`, this is the configuration :

```
services:
    app_bundle.general:
        class: AppBundle\Services\General
```

I'm trying to set this service as a global variable for my twig templates, so in config.yml I added (like the documentation say) :

```
parameters:
    general_service: "@services.app_bundle.general"
```

But with this I have this error : `You cannot dump a container with parameters that contain references to other services (reference to service "services.app_bundle.general" found in "/general_service").`

How can I set my service to a global variable for Twig ? And in twig, use it like : `{{general_service.myMethod()}}`

Thanks !

Comment: Try to add it to `twig:` under `globals:` key.

Comment: If I do that I have this error : The service "twig" has a dependency on a non-existent service "services.app_bundle.general".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Artamiel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2763926/artamiel) suggested, add your service to the twig engine `globals`:

```
#app/config/config.yml
twig:
    globals:
        general_service: "@app_bundle.general"
```

Please note: your service has the id `app_bundle.general` and **not** `services.app_bundle.general` as indicated in your example.